# Find span tag inside jquery tab and return that index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery tab UI for creating my tabs. I hided span tag with unique value in each tabs. I would like to find span tag with values with the particular tab index.

Example::

If there is a two tabs tab1 and tab2. In tab1 i hide value '1' and in tab 2 value '2'. Now i want to search in all tabs and find 1 and return the index number in this case it will be 0. Then it will open that tab with the index '0'.

I can use jquery contain function for searching thorugh list but i just wonder how can i return the particular index of tab when the match found.

Any help would greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: You need to post some code you've tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But basically you can use the `$.each()` method ([**jQuery .each() API**)](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
Within the function arguments, the `i` stands for the index, which you can loop through.

```
$('[id^="tab"]').each(function (i, el) {
    $(this).append(' -- Index: ' + i);
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNNKS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="tab"]').click(function(){

alert($(this).find('span').text());

});



$('[id^="tab"]').each(function (i, el) {

       var span_val = $(this).find('span').text(); 

       if(span_val==1)
       {
          $('[id^="tab"]').eq(span_val).trigger('click');
       }  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If every tab has only one span, you can find index like this (not the shortest way but should work):

```
var tabMenu = $('#yourTabMenuId');
var allTabMenuSpans = tabMenu.find('span');
var spanMatch = allTabMenuSpans.filter(":contains('1')");
var desiredIndex = allTabMenuSpans.index(spanMatch);
alert('your index is: ' + desiredIndex);
```

or you can just lookup the [index() method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of jquery and implement it your way.